# Find two consecutive non-empty lines

Tags: search, regular-expression

I want to find two consecutive non-empty lines.

```
AAA
BBB

    AAA
BBB

AAA
    BBB

    AAA
    BBB
```

The file above shows four pairs of consecutive non-empty lines. All of the lines can have trailing white space

I tried `^\s*\S\+\n\s*\S+` But that does not do the job. Moreover, it does not account for trailing spaces. I tried `^\s*\S\+\s*$\n\s*\S+\s*$` too. But no luck again.

So, how do I search for such lines? And it would be great if you could explain your solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
/.*\S.*\n.*\S
```

That finds a line containing at least one non-space character (\S) followed by another line containing at least one non-space character. That assumes that "non-empty" means containing at least one non-space character.